# Problem validating a string inside a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to look for a string inside a dataframe column, but when I try to look for it using the 'in' operator it always returns me 'False', anyone knows why?
My dataframe print showing the description is [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nruzP.png)

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Gabriel, Welcome to the So,  its always advisable to show your data in text form with minimal data you can so others can reproduce it.

Comment: This is a duplicate, see that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df["Nome"].str.contains("Karla")
```

If you just want to check if "Karla" is anywhere in the column:

```
any(df["Nome"].str.contains("Karla"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways you can get the desired data from your dataFrame:

Using `str.contains` ...

```
df1[df1['Nome'].str.contains('Karla')]
```

OR

```
df1[df1.Nome.str.contains("Karla") == True]
```

OR

```
df1[df1['Nome'].str.contains("Karla") == 0]
```

Using `isin` ...

```
df1[ df1['Nome'].isin(["Karla"])]
```

Using `equal to of dataframe and other, element-wise (binary operator eq).`

```
df1[df1.Nome == "Karla"]
```

OR

```
df1[df1['Nome'].eq("Karla")]
```